# How many colors can colorblind people really see compared to normal color vision?

Tags: vision, color

A person with normal vision, [it seems](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+color+can+human+see), can see 7,000,000 colors.

How many can a colorblind person see?

I'm not as much interested in the exact number, or the technicalities that might exist due to different types of color blindness (let's just consider the most prevalent colorblindness, which is red-green I think) but I'm more interested in how low or what percentage would that number be w.r.t. to the normal vision? Is it like half, or only 10%, or much closer like 90%?

This is sort of a follow up of [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/if-people-with-colorblindness-lack-one-type-of-cone-cells-shouldnt-they-be-una). If 3 cone cells can see between 7,000,000 colors, how many would 2 see?